# WooCommerce Div layout

Tags: css, layout, woocommerce

For some reason the layout of the woo commerce plugin is not aligning properly and seems to be consistently stretched on every page.

[image]

---

I have tried switching to different themes but the problem persists.

I have not changed any of the CSS so wondering if it is a plugin conflict or something else with the CSS?

Any insights would be hugely appreciated. Link to the page where it keeps failing is here

http://windsordi.eu/product/gold-package/

Comment: I don't see what you mean. What is stretched?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D . The above page seems ok but if you add it to Cart , the woocommerce plugin on the Cart & Check out page seems to take up the whole page. I uploaded a screenshot of what it looks like to this page http://windsordi.eu/problem/    ; but the problem can be replicated if you add it to the cart and go to the cart or checkout page. Hugely appreciated if you can help out with this.

Comment: </style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='storefront-woocommerce-style-css'  href='http://windsordi.eu/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css?ver=4.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='storefront-woocommerce-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
Any ideas if this is the right place to resolve the problem of the DIV containers of the checkout being stretched ?